Cyclic folding for markdown in vscode
I am looking for a useful feature that I am missing back then when using emacs org-mode. In org-mode there is Visibility cycling. Where if you are on certain header, using tab key you go for FOLDED -> CHILDREN -> Subtree. Which are level of unfolding that affects visibility.
On the other hand, shift-tab, do similar thing, but for the entire headers.
So in essence, each of tab and shift-tab should be able to toggle 3 states. In Vscode, I can only fold and unfold entire headlines or the single headline I am at, without the same granularity of controlling subtrees and siblings.
Is there is any snippets or extensions capable of doing so?

From: Cycling visibility/collapsing content #70 i do see: Any workaround to cycle visibility? #196, which is still Open today

I don't want to use org files anymore. I was thinking of this functionality in markdown

"I don't want to use org files anymore": I have no clue what that is about, I do not know emacs. Maybe you should give some examples of (visible)text before and after a desired shortcut? Someone with skills, that had the time to read Key Bindings for Visual Studio Code, might know a way of doing it.
